# Is Dell PERC H330 for RAID 5 compatible with a dual-boot Ubuntu and Win10 setup?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, raid, raid5

On my current setup, I have Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 in dual boot. On Ubuntu, I have created a software RAID 5 with mdadm. I have had this setup for years, and never had a problem.

However, I am looking for a RAID 5 solution to which I will have access both through Windows and Linux.

I see that the Dell PERC H330 [is certified by Canonical](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/scsi/4755/scsi%3APERCH330/). If I buy this controller, and create a RAID 5.0 with NTFS, will I be able to access it both from Ubuntu and Windows?

I Intent to use the RAID exclusively for data storage, neither of the OSs will be on it.